# how to install fonts with an app packaged with the desktop app converter

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have created an app package from a win32 app using the Desktop App Converter. It needs to install two truetype fonts in order to display music. It uses the windows.sharedFonts extension in the AppxManifest.xml for this purpose. When I submit to the store I receive the following error:

Package acceptance validation error: You can't use extension windows.sharedFonts with this account. Contact our support team if you'd like to request permissions to use this extension.

Is there a better alternative to install these fonts? Otherwise how do I best contact the support team?

Answer (score 2):

You could contact the dev centre team via [aka.ms/storesupport](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) the same as one would for any other publishing permissions issue.

[image]

If you only need the fonts in their app then you can include them there and use them directly. SharedFonts is only needed to provide fonts to other applications on the system.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up having the app install the fonts. I was also able to contact the store support as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to create an appx/msix package you should start looking at the [MSIX Packaging tool](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/MSIX-Blog/MSIX-Packaging-Tool-Released-to-the-Microsoft-Store/ba-p/272841) (*now publicly available, not just for Windows Insider*) or free tools like [Advanced Installer Express](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html) (recommended by MSFT), the Desktop App Converter is kind of discontinued.

Now, **regarding fonts**, as you can see in [this thread on the MSIX community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/MSIX-Deployment/No-support-for-packaged-fonts/m-p/228381) this is on their roadmap for MSIX packages. I haven't test any older appx packages, but since MSIX is an update for AppX I doubt they ever worked for packages created with the Desktop App Converter either.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*